# Trouble with checkboxes in Google Maps API 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, checkbox, google-maps-markers

I am trying to display a large amount of markers on a google maps page embedded on my website. Currently, I have the map and the markers working, but I am also trying to be able to sort through these markers with 4 checkboxes that I added to the code.

However, the checkboxes do not do anything when they are checked. I have been trying to figure out the problem with my code for a few days now, but I cannot put my finger on the issue.

```
['Anchorage Air Route Traffic Control Center (ZAN)', 61.228391,-149.779551,1], 
['Anchorage TRACON (A11)', 61.17736,-149.979644,2],
['Allentown Tower (ABE)', 40.658666,-75.440991,3],
['Anchorage ATCT (ANC)', 61.177515,-149.979644,4],
var markers = [];     
var i, newMarker;     
for (i = 0; i < facilities.length; i++) 
{newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({        
position: new google.maps.LatLng(facilities[i][1], facilities[i][2]),    
map: map,
title: facilities[i][0],
clickable:true,
zindex: 10,      
});
newMarker.category = facilities[i][3];      
newMarker.setVisible(true);       
markers.push(newMarker);

}   


 function displayMarkers(categ) {      
var i, categ;       
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {        
if (markers[i].category === categ && markers[i].getVisible()== true) 
{         
 markers[i].setVisible(false);        
 } 
else if (markers[i].category === categ && markers[i].getVisible()== false) 
{
    markers[i].setVisible(true);        
}
 }    
}
```

Then, in the body of the page, I have:
    
    id="artccb" value="ARTCC" onclick="displayMarkers(1)">
    ARTCC

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"           
id="traconb" value="TRACON" onclick="displayMarkers(2)">     
<label>TRACON</label>  

<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"           
id="bothb" value="ATCT/TRACON" onclick="displayMarkers(3)">     
<label>ATCT/TRACON</label> 

 <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"           
id="atctb" value="ATCT" onclick="displayMarkers(4)">     
<label>ATCT</label> 

</div> 

<body onload="initialize()">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the part where you add markers to the map in separate function? If so then `markers` array is not visible in `displayMarkers` function.
Put `var markers = [];` in global scope and it should work.
EDIT: by global scope i mean:

```
var markers = [];
function initialize() {
...
}
function displayMarkers(...
```

EDIT 2:
Also in `displayMarkers` replace:

```
var i, categ;
```

With

```
var i;
```

You should't redefine `categ` variable because it is passed as a parameter.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I am new to this type of programming, and do not know what you mean by global scope. The markers being added to the map is a seperate function, so this seems to be the issue. Could you explain the global scope a little more? Thanks.

Comment: If you define variable outside any function then it's in global scope. So put `var markers=[];` before you start to define your init function.

Comment: I tried defining the markers variable before the init function, but the checkboxes still do not toggle the markers. Still not sure what the problem is. Do you have any other suggestions?